# FBProfilePictureView loading with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbconnect

I'm setting the FBProfilePictureView with the user id but it takes a while, so i'd like to know if there is anything that indicates when the loading is done, so i can show an ActivityIndicator

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [SDWebImage librabry](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), you will be able to put a placeholder while loading your picture or add a progress indicator. I think everything you need is there.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no delegate or something similar in FBProfilePictureView that indicates when the image finished loading. Looking at the source code (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/UI/FBProfilePictureView.m) it seems like it should be fairly easy to fork the repo and add a few changes to notify you when the HTTP request has finished.